# Determine image value by image name

Tags: java, design, swing

I'm making a blackjack game, and I want to take my cards images and give each a value for the game.

I'm not sure how to determine their value. Should I just do a big switch statement with all the images names?

Or maybe should I check for contains with a big if statement? Like if the image name contains "king", then the value is 10, or maybe there is another way which is more efficient?

Comment: The logic should be in charge, not the visuals. Ensure you have a working `Card` or `Deck` class or whatever, then ensure that the correct image is loaded for the correct card.

Comment: **NB:** Stack Exchange requires much higher standards from question askers than this.  I suggest you take some time and become familiar with the network and its social norms before asking your next question.

Comment: Since you're using Java, you should be leveraging the object oriented paradigm.... in which case, wouldn't it make sense for each `Card` object to have a value field?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using strings to control your logic when there are better types available. (Using strings for everything is called [stringly typed code](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) and is considered an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).) A better choice for representing the values cards can have would either be a simple `int` or an `enum`. I'd probably use an `int` between 2 and 9 for the numbered cards and use 10, 11, 12, and 13 for jack, king, queen, and ace.

I'd use an enum to represent the suits: hearts, spades, diamonds, and clubs. Something like this:

```
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS
}
```

As suggested in the comments, I'd create a `Card` class. Each object in the `Card` class would have a `Suit` and a value between 2 and 13 inclusive. You could create a `Deck` class that held all 52 cards. It could have methods for shuffling the cards and dealing cards.

Answer (score 0):

Have a Card class with members Value, ImageFileName, Image, Position, etc. and use an object oriented approach.